# What year did the Unix "tar" program get released?

Tags: linux, tar

Here's an simple question: what year did the Unix "tar" (TApe ARchive) come out? I wasn't able to find the answer with Internet searches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> First Edition UNIX included a tape backup program called "tap". Since
>   it was designed around the capabilities of the First Edition
>   filesystem, it did not have a concept of "group" (First Edition only
>   had "user" and "other" permission bits) and used a 16-bit time format.
>   Fourth Edition UNIX extended the file system capabilities and replaced
>   "tap" with a new "tp" program for creating and reading tape backups.
>   Similarly, when Seventh Edition UNIX was released in January 1979, it
>   featured a new set of file system features and a new tape backup
>   program called "tar" (for "Tape ARchiver").

So, 1979 it is.

Source : https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/FormatTar

Comment: Great job, RBK!!

Answer (score 3):

tar wasn't in [v6](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/1/), but was in [v7](http://cm.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/index.html), if that helps.

Comment: You're absolutely correct!

Answer (score 2):

> GNU tar is the default on most GNU/Linux distributions. It is based on the public domain implementation pdtar which started in 1987.

From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tape_archive).

Answer (score 0):

> The format was created in the early days of Unix and standardized by POSIX.1-1988

1988

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tape_archive