# Why am I getting an error: "Failed to open '/dev/st0'" when extracting an archive with bsdtar?

Tags: rhel, tar

I installed `bsdtar` from source (from the libarchive website) because I could not find an `rpm` nor a package in `yum`.

I'm able to see `bsdtar`'s help message. For example:

```
$ bsdtar --help
First option must be a mode specifier:
  -c Create  -r Add/Replace  -t List  -u Update  -x Extract
Common Options:
...
bsdtar 3.1.2 - libarchive 3.1.2
```

But when I try to extract a file, I get the following error:

```
$ bsdtar -xzC . < archive.tar.gz
bsdtar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '/dev/st0'
```

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `x` mode, [all POSIX-compliant versions of `tar` require `-f`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/tar.html) to read the input archive from somewhere other than the default. To read from `stdin`, POSIX also requires that you give `-` as the file name:

```
$ tar -xf - < file.tar
```

Both GNU `tar` and `bsdtar` understand that syntax.

GNU `tar` differs from POSIX in that it will accept a `tar` archive on `stdin` *without* an explicit `-f -` argument. In fact, POSIX says that without `-f -`, it should not use `stdin` at all. It is clear from your question that you're getting your command line examples from a GNU `tar` user.

[`bsdtar` follows POSIX](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/ManPageBsdtar1) in requiring `-f -` if you want it to read from `stdin` rather than a file.

That brings us to your actual question: when not given `-f -`, why does `bsdtar` choose to read from `/dev/st0`? That's the default I mentioned above. POSIX only says this default is "system-dependent;" `bsdtar` chooses to use the name of the first [tape drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tape_drive)'s [dev node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Unix_and_Unix-like_systems), which happens to be `/dev/st0` on Linux.<sup>1</sup>

You need to say this instead:

```
$ bsdtar -xf - < archive.tar.gz
```

Or, skip the redirection entirely:

```
$ bsdtar -xf archive.tar.gz
```

I removed `-z` because both `bsdtar` and GNU `tar` will detect `gzip` compression in `x` mode automatically. (Old versions of GNU `tar` did require a compression type flag, but [autodetection was added in version 1.15](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/tar.git/plain/NEWS), released in 2004.)

I also removed the `-C .` bit since it just tells `bsdtar` to change to the current directory before unpacking the archive. It's a [no-op](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP).

---

1. Why default to the first tape drive? Because [`tar` is the Tape ARchiver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)). `tar` comes from [a time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67436/what-year-did-the-unix-tar-program-get-released/67439#67439) when most every Unix box did in fact have a tape drive.

Comment: Ah, that made it work. Thanks for the help. Would you suggest I use a different archiving utility? I'm basically looking for something that's as close as possible to tar on OS X. Running `tar --version` on OS X gives me `bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3`.

Comment: It seems that you don't actually know `bsdtar` very well, so I don't see why you're anxious to have it. It seems that you're getting GNU tar commands from somewhere and are trying to apply it to `bsdtar`, so it's probably better to go the other direction: get GNU tar for OS X, and make it the default. I suggest installing [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), then `brew install gnu-tar`, then add `alias tar=gtar` to your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I'm using `bsdtar` over `gtar` because the former can handle `zip` archives in addition to just `tar` and `tar.gz`. Using `bsdtar`, I can extract any archive (at least these three) and not worry about their types.

Comment: As you wish. Personally, I've been using the [Info-ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infozip) utilities for that, going back to my DOS days in the early 1990s. Both the OS X box I'm typing this on and the CentOS 6 VM running on it both have `unzip` on them, and I'm pretty sure I didn't add either after the fact.